# Excel Formula If Statement - in between percentages

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, nested-if

Here is what I am trying to do:

I have one column (lets say Column A) of percentages (ranging from 100% to 0%). I have a second column (lets say Column B) with a number 1-10. I want to create a third column which adds together whatever number is in Column B, and the following: If the percentage is 99-90, add 1. If 89-80, add 2. 79-70, add 3. 69-60, add 4. 59-50, add 5. 49-40, add 6. 39-30, add 7. 29-20, add 8. 19-10, add 9. under 10, add 10.

However, I can't seem to write it properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did any of the proposed solutions work for you? If so, then please acknowledge, and if not then please point out what's not working for you. Thx.

Comment: his is working awesome so far! - thank you. However, the method suggested by Miqi180 means that even if a percentage is at 100, that it is still adding "1" to column C, which I can't have. If the percentage is at 100, I need nothing added. Could you offer any more help?

Comment: That is incorrect. Please see my comment below my post for further explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would go at it.  Assuming you are using columns A and B, and data starts on row2.

=B2+IF(A2<0.1,10,IF(A2<=0.19,9,IF(A2<=0.29,8,IF(A2<0.39,7,IF(A2<=0.49,6,IF(A2<=0.59,5,IF(A2<=0.69,4,IF(A2<=0.79,3,IF(A2<=0.89,2,IF(A2<=0.99,1))))))))))

Also worth noting that you stated the percentages would be from 0% to 100%, yet 100% is not part of any of your data forks.

Hope this works!

[image]

Comment: I dont have a high enough reputation to comment on @miqi180, so I'll comment here...    His answer is definitely better.  I did not realize there was actually a reasoning, or formula to determine your thresholds.  My way of using multiple `IF` statements has one small benefit, and it's that you can control the value you assign to each of your forks.  I definitely like the `FLOOR` option in this particular case.

Comment: You are welcome.  One thing you may also want to do is put your forks in a small table that contains your thresholds, and replace the hard values with vlookups to that table.  It's initially a bit more complex to write, but enables you to easily change your forks very efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

A far simpler solution is possible. Provided your percentages are values ranging from 0 to 1 in column A starting at row 1, you can obtain the values you want by adding the following formula in cell C1 and copy-pasting it to the bottom row:

```
=10*(1-FLOOR(A1;0,1))+B1
```

If your locale is not North European as mine, then change `0,1` to `0.1`.

**Edit**

Thanks to `pnuts` the correct syntax on other locales is in fact to change `;0,1` to `,0.1`.

For the sake of comparison, I've used the same values as `Nickstoy` in the first 10 rows.

**Example**

[image]

Comment: @pnuts Thx. It appears you're right according to http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/floor.php

Comment: Excellent. Point settled then. I guess your phrasing "might need" threw me off there :)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'm glad I normally program in VBA where this is a non-issue, since the syntax is always the same regardless of locale.

Comment: True. It's a bit messy to switch between syntaxes or conventions, but the compiler will soon tell you if you got it wrong. The same is often true here on SO ;-)

Comment: This is working awesome so far! - thank you. However, the method suggested by Miqi180 means that even if a percentage is at 100, that it is still adding "1" to column C, which I can't have. If the percentage is at 100, I need nothing added. Could you offer any more help?

Comment: That is incorrect. If the value in col A is 1, then `1-FLOOR(A1,0.1)` becomes zero, which means only the value in col B is added and not the value in col B + 1. In other words, if the percentage is 100, the value in col B is equal to the value in col C. Please refer to row 6 of my example. P.S. if this works for you, you might want to accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Telling someone their question is incorrect might not be the most amicable answer...

I still don't really understand the 0,13 or how that is representative of 19-10%. And, by the way, using your example does NOT work when the percentage is 100...though you were much closer than I ever could be. So regardless, thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, I certainly didn't mean to sound too harsh, but given your specification of the problem and the fact that my formula yields the exact same results as `Nickstoy's`, which you accepted, and is much more simple, it does seem that you're in fact wrong here. Especially considering you don't even seem to understand why 0.13 is representative of 10-19%...